# arp-scan command displays (Unknown)

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-monitoring

this command  `sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet` display the following results:

```
192.168.1.1   *:*:*:*:*:*   D-Link Corporation
192.168.1.101 *:*:*:*:*:*   (Unknown)
```

why i can't see the name of the host ....101? why it display (Unknown)??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third column after executing the displays the vendor recognized by `arp-scan`. In the case of `(Unknown)`, it means that `arp-scan` is unable to recognize it.

From [nta-monitor.com](http://www.nta-monitor.com/wiki/index.php/Arp-scan_User_Guide#MAC_Vendor_Decoding):

> If you find a system that arp-fingerprint reports as UNKNOWN, and you know what operating system it is running, please send details of the operating system and fingerprint to arp-scan@nta-monitor.com so I can include it in future versions. Please include the exact version of the operating system if you know it, as fingerprints sometimes change between versions.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as completed :)